# Change speed needle with KeyCode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script which shows a speedometer at the beginning with 0km/h. Now I would like to increase the speed with the help of KeyCodes like "UpArrow" and decrease with "DownArrow".
Thanks for your help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewSpeedometer : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    public float maxSpeed = 0.0f; // The maximum speed of the target ** IN KM/H **

    public float minSpeedArrowAngle;
    public float maxSpeedArrowAngle;

    [Header("UI")]
    public Text speedLabel; // The label that displays the speed;
    public RectTransform arrow; // The arrow in the speedometer

    private float speed = 0.0f;
    private void Update()
    {
        

        if (speedLabel != null)
            speedLabel.text = ((int)speed) + " km/h";
        if (arrow != null)
            arrow.localEulerAngles =
                new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Lerp(minSpeedArrowAngle, maxSpeedArrowAngle, speed / maxSpeed));
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Update() you should put an if(Input.GetKey(keycode.uparrow)) and inside it set the speed to augment by a value multiplied by Time.deltaTime and a value that you can call acceleration for example.

For the deceleration you can do the same thing but substring the value from speed.